# Integrate Membership Provider with AspNet Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, webforms, identity, membership

I have two ASP.NET web applications.

1. A legacy web forms application built using .Net Framework 4.6.1 with a Membership Provider
2. An AspNet Core application that uses Core Identity 2.1

The two web applications comprise the overall web application.

The plan is to have both applications hosted in IIS and allow the Core web application to manage authentication/authorization for both web apps.

I have already implemented cookie sharing between the two applications using an OWIN startup class in the web forms app and corresponding middle-ware in the Core app.

The flow is as follows:

1. The requests coming into the webforms application will be intercepted by a Http moudule which will redirect to the AspNet Core login form if the user is not authenticated.
2. Once the user enters their credentials in the Core Login form, they are redirected back to the Web forms application Home page or whatever other page as if they had logged into the app directly.

The issue I am currently having is that I haven't been able to find a programmatic way of authenticating the user as though they had submitted the Login form in the web forms app.

Is there a way to programmatically authenticate a user by using the Membership Provider via Core Identity?